# In bitkeeper/bk, how do I list all untracked files in my repository?

Tags: version-control, bitkeeper

In bitkeeper/bk, how do I list all untracked files in my repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
bk extras
```

you can also do

```
bk sfiles -xg
```